# How to enable Gzip compression?

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess, gzip

I need to setup Gzip compression for a Magento project. I have tried many code in the `.htaccess` file in my project, but weren't able to enable Gzip.

Please give me the right solution.

Comment: Are you talking about gzip compression to improve site performance?

Comment: yes,  tell me how to compression?

Comment: Have you solve this problem yet??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure `mod_deflate` is on in Apache. You can check by creating an `info.php` file and calling `phpinfo();`. It will output server PHP / Apache specs in the browser. Don't forget to remove it when you're done!

Then add the following to your `htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    ## enable resulting html compression
   php_flag zlib.output_compression on
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    ## Force compression for mangled `Accept-Encoding` request headers
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    ## Compress all output labeled with one of the following media types.
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                      "application/javascript" \
                                      "application/json" \
                                      "application/ld+json" \
                                      "application/manifest+json" \
                                      "application/rdf+xml" \
                                      "application/rss+xml" \
                                      "application/schema+json" \
                                      "application/vnd.geo+json" \
                                      "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                      "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                      "application/x-javascript" \
                                      "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
                                      "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                      "application/xml" \
                                      "font/eot" \
                                      "font/opentype" \
                                      "image/bmp" \
                                      "image/svg+xml" \
                                      "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
                                      "image/x-icon" \
                                      "text/cache-manifest" \
                                      "text/css" \
                                      "text/html" \
                                      "text/javascript" \
                                      "text/plain" \
                                      "text/vcard" \
                                      "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
                                      "text/vtt" \
                                      "text/x-component" \
                                      "text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
                                      "text/xml"

    </IfModule>

    ## Map the following filename extensions to the specified
    ## encoding type in order to make Apache serve the file types
    ## with the appropriate `Content-Encoding` response header
    ## (do note that this will NOT make Apache compress them!).
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        AddEncoding gzip              svgz
    </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: hello sander code do not work. i add this code but can not g.zip enable.

Comment: I'll need a bit more than that to help you. Any errors or hints on whats not working?

Comment: website is proper work but when i check from this link http://checkgzipcompression.com than show G.zip not enable.

Comment: Are you sure mod_deflate is on?

Comment: yes, sure node is on

Comment: I am on shared hasting with https..this seems not allowing me to get compressed response. Any idea?

Comment: @AnuragKhandelwal so I'm guessing they don't have the mod turned on. Create a phpinfo page if you will. that should display it